# When error message shows, disable accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-validate

I am using accordion jQuery UI in order to organize huge number of input elements, and using Validation Engine plugin to validate my input types.

My problem is: when the first accordion input element shows error message, I can easily go through second accordion and the error message lost position.

I want that when error message shows the accordion will be disabled.

I am using the code below but it doesn't work. (always hanging accordion UI)

```
if($("#formID").validationEngine({returnIsValid:false})) {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        event: false
    });
}
else event:true;
```

Please give me any suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("#accordion").accordion( "disable" );` ([docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#method-disable)).

Comment: always gets true, because input type field doesn't reload to back false result. any after click event has, to check after input, What validation is back, true or false.. thank u very much for replaying.